# OPening a file on a remote computer

Tags: c#, c, windows

OS: Windows Language: C#/C/C++

Does anyone know how to open a file in Remote computer.
I could find few samples for unix but not for windows. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Too unspecific. How do you want to access that file? SMB? FTP? SCP? ...?

Comment: There is no language C#/C/C++. In C the usual way to open files is with the `fopen()` function (prototype in `<stdio.h>`); for example: `h = fopen("remote_computer/path/to/file", "r"); if (!h) /* handle error */;`

Comment: @pmg 
The machine is available in local network but other domain. I have the credentials for the machine and domain. However, how would you intimate the credential during fopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply specify the UNC name of the file in your fopen() statement.  Like //server/share/filename.  The remote machine must be configured to support file sharing and the user account under which your program runs must have sufficient access rights.  If "remote" means through the Internet then you have to use one of the standard Internet protocols.  FTP or HTTP are typical.

Comment: don't forget the ever popular WebDAV ;)

Comment: the machine is available in local network but other domain. I have the credentials for the machine and domain. However, how would you intimate the credential during fopen.

Comment: Ask the admin to create a user account on the machine so you can access the share.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to execute commands on a remote computer, on a specific session if you like.
PowerShell is another alternative. You can call PowerShell scripts from within C#.